# Repeating command with different filenames

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, zsh

Here's a layup for someone...

I'm having to run a command repeatedly:

```
$ wp input csv MyCSV01.csv directory_name
$ wp input csv MyCSV02.csv directory_name
$ wp input csv MyCSV03.csv directory_name
```

The only change is the filename is incrementing. How can I run all these back to back?

Perhaps find all the files that start with `MyCSV*` and then run them in order? And/or specify a range of the files to run `MyCSV03.csv` through `MyCSV05.csv`?

Ideally, the solution is short enough for the command line, but it could be a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in {01..20}; do  #replace with your own range
   echo \
   wp input csv "MyCSV$i.csv" directory_name
done
```

Comment out the echo line if it gives you the results you want.

`zsh`, which you tagged your question with, has a shorter form:

```
for i (MyCSV{01..20}.csv) wp input csv $i directory_name
```

Or you could use its `zargs` function:

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -i MyCSV{01..20} -- wp input csv {} directory_name
```

Comment: i like that backslashed comment thing. im going to use that, i think, if you dont mind.

Comment: And if the substitutes become more complex, you might want to use `MyCSV${i}.csv` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
for   csv in MyCSV[01][0-9].csv
do    wp  input "$csv" directory_name
done
```

Answer (score 3):

In zsh

```
: MyCSV<01-20>.csv(e*'wp input csv $REPLY directory_name'*)
```

Comment: Thumbs up llua and keep 'em coming !

Comment: Note that `<01-20>` is the same as `<1-20>` and will match `1`, `01`, `00001`...