# Repeating command line argument

Tags: shell, shell-script, arguments

I want to start off by distinguishing that [Repeating command with different filenames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246950/repeating-command-with-different-filenames) is not what I am asking.

My question is, how do you build a single command with a directory of filenames in it, each prepended with the --thingy part of the command? In my specific application, I'm using GATK (though this question is about building the command line call), and even more specifically [GenotypeGVCFs](https://www.broadinstitute.org/gatk/guide/tooldocs/org_broadinstitute_gatk_tools_walkers_variantutils_GenotypeGVCFs.php). My problem is that the command should look like:

```
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
-T GenotypeGVCFs \
-R reference.fasta \
--variant sample1.g.vcf \
--variant sample2.g.vcf \
-o output.vcf
```

but I have 93 variant files, and so the `--variant` line needs to be repeated 93 times, each with a different filepath. They're all in the same directory together, and they all have the same extension (*.g.vcf).

I've looked at doing something with `find -exec +` but couldn't think of a way to get the `--variant` attached to each result. `xargs` also seems promising, but I don't understand what it does super well, and so was having trouble setting it up. At this point, I might just have a Python script generate the command and then just paste it into the terminal, but I wanted to know if there's a "correct" way to do this for future.

Comment: What happens if you put a wildcard in front of g.vcf?

Comment: That'll give a list with exactly 1 `--variant` where I need the `--variant` bit to repeat for each thing in the glob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, this might help, but I have never tried such a thing. If I were you I would just test it with some sort of `echo` command first, before launching the `java` program.

```
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
-T GenotypeGVCFs \
-R reference.fasta \
$(for v in *.g.vcf;do echo --variant ${v}" \\";done) -o output.vcf
```

Comment: `$(printf ' --variant "%s" \\\n' *.g.vcf)`

Comment: Testing it with echo, it at least generates the correct string. Be back soon to let you know if it runs correctly too!

Comment: This works with the caveat that " \\" should just be " ". The slashes are to make the multiline command work, but it appears that it interprets the loop as 1 line and does so literally (so the '\' ends up in the call). Adding in a newline as in Costas would maybe solve this? Otherwise excellent!
Also, @Costas, for some reason, printf kept stripping out the escaped characters, so I just got a big jumble. Honestly, I didn't put much effort into figuring out why though, since Mel's solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to get the list you want, and manipulate each element.  Try changing to the directory with your variant files, and something like

```
FILES=$(ls | sed 's/^/--variant /')
echo ${FILES}
```

Then just substitute ${FILES} into your command.

HTH.